# How can I rewrite a code for php server to a code for Apache?

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible that a code written for php server could be rewritten for apache server? Is it even a legal question in the first place? I have very little experience on server-side technologies.
THanks

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing apples and oranges.

Apache is an HTTP server (well, a generic TCP/IP server with a strong focus on HTTP).
PHP is a programming language.

Software written in PHP can run on a variety of servers, so long as they support PHP. Apache can run software written in PHP via mod_php, mod_cgi, and a few other modules.

Apache can run software written in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has the ability to serve PHP - read more at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to rewrite anything. Php is a language which can be processed by Apache server.

Php is a language as is say ASP among others,
Apache is a web server as is say IIS among others

Apache and IIS can understand and process PHP coded sites.

You seem to discover the field, you should start by reading this kind of articles that will demistify the all the thing for you :

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/basics/client_server_architecture.php3

Good luck